# How to get Iformfile value from JObject?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, jobjectformatter

I 'm using latest .net core and I have mvc application and web Api application so mvc appliction takes request and all the data base operations are done by web api application, I got stuck most of the time related to IFormFile for uploading image so somehow I managed to get the image data and binded to the ViewModel however when I 'm passing the ViewModel as PostAsJsonAsync to web api controller who's parameter is viewmodel it didn't work so I changed to JObject and now my issue is how to extract IFormFile property from JObject as IFormFile, I 'm facing InvalidCastException error. Here is my code.

```
//HTML File
 <div class="control-label col-md-2">
                    @Html.Label("Image")
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 imgdrop">
                    <input type="file" id="file" name="file"class="form-control-file" />
                    <div class="img-wrap ">
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                        <img src="..." alt="..."  id="imgInp" class="img-fluid" />
                    </div>
                </div>

  $("#SaveDetailsId").on("click", function () {



                var formdata = new FormData();
                var table = $("#ItemListTable").DataTable();
 $.each(tableData, function (index, item) {

                    name = 'ItemList[' + index + '].SkuList'; // construct the name
                    value = item[0];
});

                formdata.append("ImageFile", jQuery("#file").get(0).files[0]);

$.ajax({
                    //headers: {
                    //    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    //    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    //},
                    url: "/Test/Test",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formdata,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (response) {
...

  });
            });

//ViewModel
public class Test
{
   public IFormFile ImageFile {get;set;}
.
.
.
}

//MVC Controller
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> BuyerCreative([FromForm]Test _viewModel)
        {
            _viewModel.Ad = _viewModel.Ad;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //Passing service base url  
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Test/Test", _viewModel);                

                if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                         }
                //returning the employee list to view  
                return View(_viewModel);
            }

        }
//Let me know if there is a way to bind ViewModel instead of JObject
//WEbApi
[Route("api/Test/Test/")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Test([FromBody] JObject data)
        {
            try
            {

               _Repository.AddDetails(data);

                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception pException)
            {
                return BadRequest(pException.Message);
            }
        }

//And Lastly my repository


 public void AddDetails(JObject data)
{

 DBContext.Items _items = new DBContext.Items();
 _items.Number = Convert.ToInt32(((JValue)data.GetValue("Number")).Value); 

// I 'm stuck over here, how to get the IFormFile, I tried various options

 IFormFile file = (IFormFile)((JValue)data.GetValue("ImageFile"));

 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_connectionString);

                    // Create a blob client for interacting with the blob service.
                    blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                    blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);
                    blobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
                    blobContainer.SetPermissionsAsync(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });

                    var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    var parsedContentDisposition = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition);
                    fileName = parsedContentDisposition.FileName;

                    CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
                    blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file.OpenReadStream());

}
```

Comment: this generally comes directly from the controller. Where is the file coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned property, let's say there is a class with a property:

```
public class MyData
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

I can now use this in a controller:

```
public IActionResult UploadFile([FromForm]MyData data)
{

}
```

Your `data.File` will now contain the file as far as you pass form data with the right key `File`.

Comment: Hi @Neville Nazerane, that is where I 'm not stuck, the real problem is giving a call to web Api and it requires JObject, I have edited by question please check.

Comment: From all I have tried in the past, for file uploads you will have to use `[FromForm]` and the right content type. by default jquery uses text as the content type

Comment: Hi @Neville Nazerane, so what solution you recommend...I don't see a way to get out of it... any code sample if you have which is working please let me know.

Comment: i had made this upload sample recently https://github.com/neville-nazerane/netcore.azure.blob/tree/master/TestWebsite

Comment: Hi @Neville Nazerane, I will try your solution and let you know

Comment: Hi @Neville Nazerane, now if you have another project which is a web api project how will you pass model containing data + Iformfile to web api controller from web app controller..?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't bind to `JObject`. Create a real view model and bind to that.

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
public void AddDetails([FromBody]ItemViewModel data)
```

Second, to post a file via JSON, you have to send it as a base64-encoded `byte[]` (which will make it a string). The modelbinder will automatically base64-decode it back into a true `byte[]`, if that's what you're binding it to via your view model.

If you don't want to have to base64-encode it on the client-side, then you must post it as `multipart/form-data`, in which case, you'll need to bind the posted file to `IFormFile`. Which means you'd change the `File` property in the view model class above to:

```
public IFormFile File { get; get; }
```

Comment: Hi @Chris Pratt, that is where I 'm not stuck, the real problem is giving a call to web Api and it requires JObject, I have edited by question please check.

Comment: The problem is in binding to JObject in the first place. Let the modelbinder handle binding and casting as it should. You also get built-in validation, which you don't have at all with JObject. Once you have a real class you're binding to, you simply need a property of either byte[] or IFormFile, depending on what you're sending (i.e. JSON or form data). Everything just works then.

Comment: Hi @chris patt, I didnt get you, I 'm using Jobject coz thr is no way to bind except not even model classes in web api and the main probelm is using Iformfile, if you try my code you will realize the problem  and if you find any solution please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean there's no way to bind? If you can't use a real model, you're doing something wrong. Plain and simple, you can't achieve what you're trying to do with JObject. Period. End of story. Update your question with the code with a real model you think doesn't work, and we can probably help you with that, instead of insisting on continuing down this wrong path.

Comment: Hi @Chris Pratt, I guess I have mentioned number of times for IFormfile we cannot achieve the normal way for that reason JObject..now just my normal question to you how can we extract Iformfile contnt from JObject and assign it to Iformfile.. if you know the answer please help or leave it